# How to get covariance of 2 random effects in lme?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, covariance, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I am running a mediation analysis on multilevel data. I am trying to calculate covariance of 2 paths (a and b) so I can get mediation effect = ab + covar(a,b).

So I run this mixed mediation model:

```
timemod8 <- lme(selfCSI~ 0 + sm1 + sm1:SelfIS1 + sy + sy:SelfDep1 + sy:SelfIS1,data = data2, 
random=~ 0 + sm1 + sm1:SelfIS1 + sy + sy:SelfDep1 + sy:SelfIS1|CoupleID, 
               na.action = "na.omit", method = "ML",control = lmeControl(opt = "optim", weights = varIdent(form = ~1 |variable)))

SelfIS is IV, SelfDep is M, SelfCSI is DV. Here is the output: 
Random effects:
 Formula: ~0 + sm1 + sm1:SelfIS1 + sy + sy:SelfDep1 + sy:SelfIS1 | CoupleID
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev       Corr                 
sm1         1.978112e-05 sm1  sy s1:SIS sy:SD1
sy          1.767429e-05 0                    
sm1:SelfIS1 1.347347e-06 0    0               
sy:SelfDep1 5.648605e-08 0    0  0            
SelfIS1:sy  8.233455e-07 0    0  0      0     
Residual    1.151016e+01                      

Fixed effects: selfCSI ~ 0 + sm1 + sm1:SelfIS1 + sy + sy:SelfDep1 + sy:SelfIS1 
                Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
sm1         20.134590 1.0451055 3212 19.265605  0.0000
sy          20.158182 1.0451956 3212 19.286517  0.0000
sm1:SelfIS1 -0.113782 0.0852859 3212 -1.334122  0.1823
sy:SelfDep1 -0.158922 0.0924077 3212 -1.719797  0.0856
SelfIS1:sy  -0.071821 0.0887072 3212 -0.809640  0.4182
 Correlation: 
            sm1    sy     s1:SIS sy:SD1
sy           0.000                     
sm1:SelfIS1 -0.947  0.000              
sy:SelfDep1  0.000 -0.013  0.000       
SelfIS1:sy   0.000 -0.907  0.000 -0.275
```

I followed steps in this example to calculate mediation effect of SelfDep(https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-mediation-with-multilevel-data-method-2/). But when i ran this code to calculate covariance of 2 random effects SelfIS1 and SelfDep1, it comes up with **subscript out of bounds**

```
VarCorr(timemod8)[["CoupleID"]]["sm1:SelfIS1", "sy:SelfDep1"]
```

Can anyone help me this one? This is the last step to calculate my mediation effect but I am stuck for a few days now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The webpage you followed, they used lme4 whereas in your example above, you used nlme, i guess the weights? In any case, the structure of `VarCorr(timemod8)` will be very different from that in the webpage, because you are using a different package.

Hopefully you specified the random effects correctly, I am not so familiar with that in nlme, so if you look at your `VarCorr(mod)`, it's no longer a list, and `VarCorr(timemod8)[["CoupleID"]]` is going to throw you an error.

I used the example data in the website, switched to your variable names and ended up with something like this:

```
VarCorr(mod)
CoupleID = pdLogChol(0 + sm1 + sm1:SelfIS1 + sy + sy:SelfDep1 + sy:SelfIS1) 
            Variance   StdDev    Corr                       
sm1         0.68074182 0.8250708 sm1    sy     s1:SIS sy:SD1
sy          0.25811518 0.5080504  0.132                     
sm1:SelfIS1 0.12482200 0.3533016  0.062  0.069              
sy:SelfDep1 0.10341735 0.3215857  0.035 -0.036  0.845       
SelfIS1:sy  0.02386116 0.1544706 -0.045 -0.228 -0.354  0.165
Residual    0.58000711 0.7615820
```

Note under the Corr, the variable names are truncated, you can see that as well in your output. And also `VarCorr(mod)["sy:SelfDep1",]` is going to throw you a table of characters, not a matrix.

For you to continue, the value you need is the correlation between `sy` and `SelfDep1`, so from your printed output, it should be the row of `"SelfIS1:sy"`, and under the column of `"sy:SD1"`, giving you `-0.275`

Comment: Thanks for ur detailed reply. Does it mean that now i can calculate the covariance of random paths a and by SD(sm1:SelfIS1) x SD(sy:SelfDep1) x r(sm1:SelfIS1, sy:SelfDep1)? Also, in the example, they also used nlme package as well. And they used this function VarCorr(timemod8)[["CoupleID"]]["sm1:SelfIS1", "sy:SelfDep1"] to calculate covariance of the 2 random effects, so im wondering if i can do calculate it manually like I mentioned at the beginning? Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes you have to read it off the output. You got to read it carefully, lme4 was used to fit mm, see mm <- lmer(z ~ 0 + sm +..) , and this was used to calculate varcorr. mm.alt was fitted using lme in the example

Comment: the variance covariance matrix is not a matrix. it is printed. you have to calculate it manually